# Shortcuts for specific Live Path Effects (LPEs) in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, workflow

I'm using Inkscape to work with Live Path Effects (LPEs) to apply dynamic effects to my vector paths. However, I'm looking to streamline my workflow and would like to know the specific keyboard shortcuts for some LPEs.

I was wondering if anyone could provide a list of shortcuts for Live Path Effects, particularly for LPEs such as Mesh Deformation, Envelope, and others, if available.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could share these shortcuts or direct me to a reliable source that lists them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any keyboard shortcuts for the LPE effects.

Instead you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>&</kbd> to open the Path Effects panel, and start typing to search the path effects. Usually you only need to type two or three letters of an effect to find it. Once found, click on it to apply.

Inkscape does have keyboard shortcuts, but none are for individual LPE effects. You can find all the shortcuts which do exist listed under *Edit > Preferences > Interface > Keyboard*. You can also customise them there. If you want a list of shortcuts you can print out, it's published on the official Inkscape website https://inkscape.org/doc/keys.html

You can also find most of Inkscape's shortcuts by selecting the various menu items. Those which have shortcuts will show them listed next to the function name.